# Can't make custom QGraphicsItem, getting ObjectType

Tags: python, pyqt

Maybe a week ago I was asking about how to inherit and make custom classes. As it was explained you have to inherit from the module, for example in my case it is `QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem` and you need to call it with `super` or `QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.__init__(self)` like this. I've read some stuff about it and I was playing around with it quite a bit and it was working , but when today I tried `QtWidgets.QGraphicsItemit` , it didn't work. Here is my code:

```
        from PySide2 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
    
    class testUi(QtWidgets.QDialog):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self)
            self.window = 'vl_test'
            self.title = 'Test Remastered'
            self.size = (1000, 650)
    
            self.create( )
    
        def create(self):
            self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
            self.resize(QtCore.QSize(*self.size))
            self.testik = test(self)
    
            self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout( )
            self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.testik)
            self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
    
    
    class test(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
        zoom_signalA = QtCore.Signal(bool)
        zoom_signalB = QtCore.Signal(bool)
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.__init__(self)
            self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(backgroundBrush=QtCore.Qt.gray)
            self.__zoom = 0
            self.setScene(self._scene)
    
            self.graphicsItm = self._scene.addItem(graphicButton)
    
            self.setTransformationAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
            self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
            self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
            self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
            self.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(30, 30, 30)))
            self.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
            self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding))
    
    
    
        def wheelEvent(self, event):
            if event.angleDelta( ).y( ) > 0:
                factor = 1.25
                self.__zoom += 1
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self.__zoom -= 1
            self.scale(factor, factor)
            #self.zoom_signalA.emit(self.__zoom < 5)
            #self.zoom_signalB.emit(self.__zoom > 4)
    
    
    class graphicButton(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem):
        def __init__(self):
            QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.__init__(self)
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(r"C:\Users\v.afanasjevs\Desktop\gimpTest\gimpTestButtonPresedA.png")
            pixmap_item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap)
            pixmap_item.setFlags(
                pixmap_item.flags( )
                | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable
                | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable
            )
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = testUi()
        window.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 600)
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
Error :

    TypeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene.addItem' called with wrong argument types:
      PySide2.QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene.addItem(ObjectType)
    Supported signatures:
      PySide2.QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene.addItem(PySide2.QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem)
```

My guess is that I do mistake thinking that you can make everything some custom widget, like I am doing here, trying to make `QtGui.QPixmap` a graphic item. If , I am right and I am doing it wrong , then how to use virtual functions of QGraphicsItem , on my QPixmap ? (I want to make my image a button , so I guess I have to use "mousePressEvent" and etc).
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`graphicButton` is the name of your class.

By doing this `self.graphicsItm = self._scene.addItem(graphicButton)`, you pass the class as parameter.

Change it to `self.graphicsItm = self._scene.addItem(graphicButton())` to create a new instance.

Your `graphicButton` has to override `QGraphicsItem::paint` method.

But, it could also inherit from `QGraphicsPixmapItem`:

```
class GraphicButton(QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem):
    def __init__(self):
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(r"img.png")
        QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem.__init__(self, pixmap)
        self.setFlags(
            self.flags( )
            | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable
            | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable
        )
```

Comment: But if I make it inherit from QGraphicsPixmapItem I won't be able to make button out of it, right? Since there is no function like 'mousePressed' and so on.

Comment: `QGraphicsPixmapItem` inherits from `QGraphicsItem`. So, you have the same methods in both.

Comment: Can I also ask one small question ? Is there a way in this code to add more then one image ? Because you can't initialize object twice